# Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule: error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: issueLinkType for class

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am using an automation for Jira rule to be executed once the user clicks on a button. I would like to automatically create some linked issues once the user clicks on the button but I receive the following error message:

[image]
Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule:
Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule: UpdateExecutionSummary , file: SuperFeature/rest_superFeatureGenerator.groovy, error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: issueLinkType for class: SuperFeature.rest_superFeatureGenerator

How can I fix this?

```
    package SuperFeature 
    
    import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexingService
    import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEventManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent
    import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.ModifiedValue
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.util.DefaultIssueChangeHolder
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkTypeManager
    import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.link.IssueLinkCreatedEvent
    import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.link.IssueLinkDeletedEvent
    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkType
    
    
    def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')
    
    log.warn("MOUNA: ")
    
    log.warn("MOUNA COMPONENT NUMBERS : "+ issue.getComponents().size())
    
    List<String> componentList = new ArrayList<String>()
    def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext
    
    
    if (issue.getComponents().size()==0){
        log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA COMPONENTS")
        issue.update {
        String text= "Issue does not have any components\n"
        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
        }
    }else if(issue.getFixVersions().size()==0){
                log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA VERSIONS")
                issue.update {
                    String text= "Issue does not have any fix versions\n"
                    setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
                    }
    
        
    }
    
    else{
                log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA ELSE")
    
            int componentSize=issue.getComponents().size()
    
            for(ProjectComponent component : issue.getComponents()) {
                    componentList.add(component.getName())
            }
    
            issue.update {
                String text= "The super feature "+issue+" will be split into "+componentSize+
                " features, one for each component:\n"
    
                for(String component: componentList){
                    text = text +"-"+ component+"\n"; 
                }
                setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
    
    }
    
    // Issue issue
    def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager
    def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.issueFactory
    def subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.subTaskManager
    def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager
    def userManager = ComponentAccessor.userManager
    
    
    
    
    
    MutableIssue newIssue= ComponentAccessor.issueFactory.issue
    
    newIssue.setProjectObject(issue.getProjectObject())
    newIssue.setSummary("MOUNA CAMELIA")
    newIssue.issueTypeId= 19
    newIssue.setAssignee(userManager.getUserByName("mouh"))
    newIssue.setDescription(issue.getDescription())
    for(String component: componentList){
        log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA component"+ component +" NEW ISSUE "+ newIssue)
    
        log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA Component "+ component+" issue.getId() "+ issue.getId()+" issueLinkType "+issueLinkType+" sequence "+ sequence)                
                        issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issue.getId(), newIssue.getId(), issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one on the last few lines of the code you have

```
for(String component: componentList){
    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA component"+ component +" NEW ISSUE "+ newIssue)
    
    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA Component "+ component+" issue.getId() "+ issue.getId()+" issueLinkType "+issueLinkType+" sequence "+ sequence)                
                        issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issue.getId(), newIssue.getId(), issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
}
```

The `issueLinkType` and `sequence` referred to in those statements aren't defined anywhere in the code. Hence those will throw a MissingPropertyException when executed.

Maybe you meant `issue.issueLinkType` or `issue.sequence`?